# Show certain rows but keep others hidden

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with an excel workbook and on one of the worksheets are rows that hide or show depending on options selected in another worksheet. The structure looks something like this

```
A
1
2
3
4

B
1
2
3
4

C
1
2
3
4
```

Where they have the option to hide all of A and B, A and C, A, B, or C. The user has the option to hide A and B or C (they must select between B or C).They also have the option to hide the individual rows under each letter. Rows 1, 2, and 3. If the option to hide 2 is checked, all "2" rows under each letter is hidden. If they unchecked this option, all 2 rows appear once more. The problem is that the "2" row of an already hidden letter will display.

I have run into a mental block, but this is what I've done. Psuedocode for readability because right now my code is messy and I hate the way vba looks. This is a logic problem more than a syntax problem anyway.

```
Property hiddenA As Bool get let
Property hiddenB As Bool get let
Property hiddenC As Bool get let


OptionButton1.Click()
     hiddenA = true
     Hide A row and all rows associated with it

OptionButton2.Click()
     HiddenA = false
     Show A row and all rows associated with it
OptionButton3.Click()
     HiddenB = false
     HiddenC = true
     Show B row and all rows associated with it
     Hide C row and all rows associated with it

OptionButton4.Click()
     HiddenB = true
     HiddenC = false
     Hide B row and all rows associated with it
     Show A row and all rows associated with it



 CheckBox1.Click()
         if CheckBox1.value = false Then
            Hide all "1" rows
         Else
            Show all "1" rows, but keep the "1"s under already hidden letters, hidden. 
            This is   the problem.
```

And so on. There are checkboxes for showing/hidden all 2, 3, and 4 rows as well.

Comment: Here is what my show/hide looks for everything 

`sheetSource.Range("11:11, 27:27, 43:43, 59:59, 75:75").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Where each range is the "1" row of each letter. And so on.

Comment: Is it always letters and numbers?  Do you always know which "header" rows?  As in are they static?

Comment: Yes, they are static. No they are not actually letters and numbers, I was just showing the structure. The actual data is meaningful to the project I am working on. For now I have taken a perhaps very lazy and inefficient means of solving this problem.

`code`

Comment: `Select Case combo
        
Case "TrueTrueFalse"
            sheetSource.Range("11:11, 59:59, 75:75").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case "TrueFalseTrue"
            sheetSource.Range("11:11, 43:43, 75:75").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case "FalseTrueFalse"
            sheetSource.Range("11:11, 27:27, 59:59, 75:75").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case "FalseFalseTrue"
            sheetSource.Range("11:11, 27:27, 43:43, 75:75").EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Where _combo BooBoolBool_ is hiddenAhiddenBhiddenC

Comment: So when one row is hidden (selected by user in checkbox), do you want all other rows to be unhidden?  Or can a user have multiple "groups" hidden?

Comment: When a checkbox unchecked, say the checkbox associated with the "1" row of every letter, the "1" row should be hidden for every letter. 

When the "1" checkbox is checked, the "1" row should appear for letters that are currently visible, skipping the "1" row of hidden letters. Otherwise you will see vagrant rows not associated with a letter. 

They can select one or more number options. They have the option to make A hidden. As well as the option to make B or C hidden.

My solution above currently fixes this, but I am 100% sure there is a much better way.

Comment: That is much more complicated.  Just to clarify, you want to be able to hide/show groups of data AND you want to be able to hide/show a certain row in each visible group?  How many rows (cases) are in each group? How many groups are in your sheet?

Comment: I would use checkboxes for all conditions (show/hide groups AND show/hide specific rows within groups)

Comment: Yes you are correct. There are 5 groups of data. In each group are 5 options to choose from.

Comment: That is more or less what my solution has done. On hide it hides all the rows it needs to because whether or not a group is hidden is irrelevant in this case.

On show, it checks a combination of Bools determining which rows to show. This is done in every checkbox click

Comment: See what you can do with the below...

Answer (score 0):

Rough outline  - UNTESTED CODE... something like this should unhide everything, check each checkbox for status, add checked boxes to range, and hide that entire range at end.

```
'CheckBox1 is Row 1 in group
'CheckBox2 is Row 2 in group
'CheckBox3 is Row 3 in group
'CheckBox4 is Row 4 in group
'CheckBox5 is Row 5 in group
'CheckBox6 is Group A
'CheckBox7 is Group B
'CheckBox8 is Group C
'CheckBox9 is Group D
'CheckBox10 is Group E

Sub CheckBoxClick() 'Assign this to all checkboxes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn off screen updating
ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Unhide all

Dim RngCnt As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurRow As Long
Dim ChkBx As OLEObject

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each ChkBx In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(ChkBx.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        Select Case ChkBx.Name
            Case "CheckBox1"
                If ChkBx.Value = True Then
                    RngCnt = Union(RngCnt, Range(Rows this chk box effects))
                End If
            Case "CheckBox2"
                If ChkBx.Value = True Then
                    RngCnt = Union(RngCnt, Range(Rows this chk box effects))
                End If
            Case ETC, ETC, ETC to "CheckBox10"
            ...
        End If
    Next ChkBx
    RngCnt.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```